# visibility of css in Ext.menu.Menu

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2

I wrote CSS for Ext.menu.Menu to make it look like
[image: drop down menu]

But when I apply it to the element "componentCls:'group-menu'" my arrows (achieved through ::before and ::after) get truncated.

[image: truncated arrows]

Is it possible to apply CSS so arrows will stay intact?

Comment: Might be a z-index issue, but there's no way to tell without a demo.

Comment: yes, it might be. I looked at z index of "shadowy" area, ExtJS assigned some big value to it, and that is why my arrow is dead. I just thought may be there is non "hacky" way to make them visible. I could try assign something like 99999999, but would not really want it.

Comment: I gave 99999999999999999999999999999, still truncated :/

Comment: There's more to z-index than just setting a big value. But as I say, no demo, no help. :-(

Comment: will try to make demo in several hours